# How to turn a set of sets to list

Tags: ocaml

So I have two modules, for ex.

```
module A = Set.Make (struct 
    type t = ...
    let compare = Stdlib.compare
end)

module B = .... (virtually the same thing)
```

Now the question, if I have n amount of elements of type A (each of them has m amount of elements type t) inside one element B, how do I get the elements of A into the list?

I know about set.elements function, but whenever I try code sort of

```
let f b = B.elements (fun a -> A.elements a) b;;
```

it gives either an error about semicolon ;; or about incorrect types. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a simple, *concrete* example. `A` describes sets of ints. `B` describes sets of sets of ints.

```
module A = Set.Make (Int)
module B = Set.Make (A)
```

Let's make a simple example of the latter:

```
let b = B.(
  empty
  |> add A.(empty |> add 1 |> add 2 |> add 1)
  |> add A.(empty |> add 4 |> add 1)
)
```

Now we can map `A.elements` to each set in `B.elements b`, or we might want a *flat* list.

```
# b |> B.elements |> List.map A.elements;;
- : int list list = [[1; 2]; [1; 4]]
# b |> B.elements |> List.concat_map A.elements;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 1; 4]
```

If we want a value of type `A.t` containing all of the values in `b`, we can use `List.fold_left`.

```
# let c : A.t = b |> B.elements |> List.fold_left A.union A.empty;;
val c : B.elt = <abstr>
# c |> A.elements;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 4]
```